# align right without overflowing the screen CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, position

Ok, I'm trying to make a menu. There is the side menu that is going to have certain elements and the top menu that is going to have other elements. I have a problem when I apply the **positio:absolute** and then a **right:0px** to align the icons and the name to the right it goes off screen because my body has a **margin-left: 280px**

```js
let menuToggleButton = document.getElementById('menu_toggle_button');
let side_menu = document.getElementById('side_menu');
let body = document.getElementById('body');

menuToggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    side_menu.classList.toggle('resize-side-menu');
    body.classList.toggle('resize-body');
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    display: flex;
}
.side-menu{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-flex;
    background: #ff000061;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: .5s;
}
.resize-side-menu{
    width: 50px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.body{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 280px;
    background: blue;
    height: 2000px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.resize-body{
    margin-left: 50px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.body .content-body{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.body .content-body .header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}
.content-items-header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: brown;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}
.body .content-body .header .content-items-header .content-search-input{
    background: white;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.body .content-body .header .content-items-header .icons-content{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="side-menu" id="side_menu">
        
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="body">
        <div class="content-body">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="content-items-header">
                    <button class="fad fa-bars" id="menu_toggle_button">open</button>
                    <div class="content-search-input">
                        <input type="text" class="search" id="search">
                        <i class="fad fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons-content">
                        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                    <img src="brain.jpg" alt="" height="35px" width="35px">
                    <span>Aldahir Ruiz Valdez</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="workspace">
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I need them to always be aligned to the right but without leaving the screen

Comment: So, in your sample code above, the things shown after pressing 'open' should always be shown after closing the menu?

Comment: exactly. But without losing the fixed property

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto` depending on what you want to achieve. `overflow: hidden;` will hide all the overflow, and `overflow: auto` will add a scroll bar if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the width of `.body` and `.header` to `calc(100% - 280px)`, when pressing the button the width is changed to `calc(100% - 50px)`. I also added a `transition: .5s;` for changing the width on the `.header` so it looks smooth (you'll see what I mean when you remove the transition). Hope this is the result you're looking for!

```js
let menuToggleButton = document.getElementById('menu_toggle_button');
let side_menu = document.getElementById('side_menu');
let body = document.getElementById('body');
let header = document.querySelector('.header');

menuToggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    side_menu.classList.toggle('resize-side-menu');
    body.classList.toggle('resize-body');
    header.classList.toggle('resize-header');
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
  display: flex;
}
.side-menu{
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #ff000061;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: .5s;
}
.resize-side-menu{
  width: 50px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.body {
  width: calc(100% - 280px);

  display: inline-flex;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 280px;
  background: blue;
  height: 2000px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.resize-body{
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: .5s;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.body .content-body{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;   
}
.body .content-body .header{
  width: calc(100% - 280px);
  transition: .5s;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
.body .content-body .header.resize-header {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  transition: .5s;
}

.content-items-header{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: brown;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
.body .content-body .header .content-items-header .content-search-input{
  background: white;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.body .content-body .header .content-items-header .icons-content{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu" id="side_menu">
        
  </div>
  <div class="body" id="body">
      <div class="content-body">
          <div class="header">
              <div class="content-items-header">
                  <button class="fad fa-bars" id="menu_toggle_button">open</button>
                  <div class="content-search-input">
                      <input type="text" class="search" id="search">
                      <i class="fad fa-search"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="icons-content">
                      <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                      <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                  <img src="brain.jpg" alt="" height="35px" width="35px">
                  <span>Aldahir Ruiz Valdez</span>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="workspace">
  
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```